# How can I build this project?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ionic-framework, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this kind of question, if not, send me in the right direction please!

I'm busy with a project but I don't know how to build it. I have basic experience with HTML, CSS, Javascript and PHP. I want to build an app, but first I need to test it with my users. So I build a first prototype of my idea which I will explain further.

**JSFiddle**

I never used JSFiddle before so I hope this works.

https://jsfiddle.net/fpuL8mw3/1/

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://i.postimg.cc/QFWTbdNS/background.png");
}

.image-row {
  margin-top: 75% !important;
}

#avatar {
  margin-left: 38%;
}

.icon-row {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
}

img.icon-morphy {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  left: 55px;
}

.donut {
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 80px;
}

img.hoverImages {
  float: left;
  animation-name: float;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes float {
  from {
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}

.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
  /* Width of the outside container */
}


/* The slider itself */

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  /* Override default CSS styles */
  appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full-width */
  height: 25px;
  /* Specified height */
  background: #d3d3d3;
  /* Grey background */
  outline: none;
  /* Remove outline */
  opacity: 0.7;
  /* Set transparency (for mouse-over effects on hover) */
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  /* 0.2 seconds transition on hover */
  transition: opacity .2s;
  visibility: visible;
}


/* Mouse-over effects */

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  /* Fully shown on mouse-over */
}


/* The slider handle (use -webkit- (Chrome, Opera, Safari, Edge) and -moz- (Firefox) to override default look) */

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  /* Override default look */
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  /* Set a specific slider handle width */
  height: 25px;
  /* Slider handle height */
  background: #4CAF50;
  /* Green background */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Cursor on hover */
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  /* Set a specific slider handle width */
  height: 25px;
  /* Slider handle height */
  background: #4CAF50;
  /* Green background */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Cursor on hover */
}
```

```html
{{ .
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Morphy
  </title>
  <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.3/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
  <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </link>
  </link>
  </meta>
  </link>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="modals">
    <!-- The modal -->
    <div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="modalLabelSmall" class="modal fade" id="smallShoes" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button aria-label="Close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">
                                    ×
                                </span>
                            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalLabelSmall">
              Beweging
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <input class="slider" id="myRange" max="100" min="1" type="range" value="50">
            </input>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row icon-row">
      <div class="col col-30">
        <img class="icon-morphy" src="https://i.postimg.cc/kV3thPBC/beweging.png">
        <svg class="donut" data-target="#smallShoes" data-toggle="modal" viewbox="0 0 42 42">
                            <circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" fill="transparent" r="15.91549430918954">
                            </circle>
                            <circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" fill="transparent" r="15.91549430918954" stroke="#d2d3d4" stroke-width="3">
                            </circle>
                            <circle class="donut-segment red-value" cx="21" cy="21" fill="transparent" r="15.91549430918954" stroke="red" stroke-dasharray="85 15" stroke-dashoffset="25" stroke-width="3">
                            </circle>
                            <circle class="donut-segment white-value" cx="21" cy="21" fill="transparent" r="15.91549430918954" stroke="white" stroke-dasharray="15 85" stroke-dashoffset="40" stroke-width="3">
                            </circle>
                        </svg>
        </img>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-30">
      </div>
      <div class="col col-30">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row image-row">
      <div class="col col-100">
        <img class="hoverImages" id="avatar" src="https://i.postimg.cc/qzFKy3rz/avatar.png">
        </img>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar bar-header bar-light">
      <h1 class="title">
        bar-light
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tabs tabs-icon-top">
    <a class="tab-item">
      <i class="icon ion-home">
                </i> Home
    </a>
    <a class="tab-item">
      <i class="icon ion-star">
                </i> Favorites
    </a>
    <a class="tab-item" href="/dashboard.html">
      <i class="icon ion-gear-a">
                </i> Settings
    </a>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
  $("#myRange").change(function() {
    var bewegingValue = $("#myRange").val();
    $(".red-value").attr("stroke-dashoffset", bewegingValue);
  });
</script>

</html>
```

On my computer my project works as intended so far but on JSFiddle it doesn't. It doesn't use the API's for some reason. I'm sorry if the code isn't formatted properly or tidy for that matter. I'm still learning and very eager to learn too. Excuse me if some things aren't right.

**Idea**

The idea of the project is an app that measures the amount of exercise, food and sleep of the user with an Apple Watch. Stepcounter or GPS for exercise, the user can input food intake and sleep is measured by a heartbeat counter. An avatar changes according to the input the app receives by the user. For example if the user sleeps well the avatar reflects that by having more open eyes. If the user doesn't sleep well the avatar reflects that too by having more closed red eyes.Above the avatar are the meters for exercise, food intake and sleep. They reflect the levels of the user, if the circles are filled the user is healthy and if they are empty the user is unhealthy.

**Concept**

For my concept I'm trying the following. I want to test a prototype with my users on their mobile phone. The app is coded in HTML, CSS, Javascript, Bootstrap, Ionic and Jquery. When an user presses the circle of exercise, food or sleep an input overlay opens and the user can enter the amount of time they spent exercising, sleeping or the amount of calories they consumed. After confirming the input the avatar changes to a new version and the right meter gets updated to reflect the input.

**Visual explanation**

https://docdro.id/Zaq2SbN

**Adobe XD prototype**

https://xd.adobe.com/view/1b38a873-57a3-4c1d-4ff8-875b026eaba4-6d09/

Help of any kind is much appreciated!

Comment: Change your `http` call to Ionic's CSS to `https`. Chrome doesn't allow you to load resources over http anymore. `http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.3/css/ionic.css` should be `https://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.3/css/ionic.css`

Comment: Hi Teqhniq, welcome to StackOverflow! Your question would be easier to answer if you defined what  "build" means to you. JS, HTML, and CSS are static and do not generally require a build - if you serve all 3 to a user, and they open the html file that properly links to the JS and CSS it uses, that is all you need. You may just be looking for a way to host a static website on line - one easy way is to use GitHub's Pages feature.

Comment: By build I mean how can I approach this project? I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: First would be to try using some framework such as angular + ionic. This might be a lot of things to understand at first but in real, you could do this app in about few hours until you get finished apk file for mobile phone.